# Mongoose models using ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let modelSchema = new Schema({createdAt: {type: Number}}, { strict: false});

modelSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.createdAt = new Date().getTime() - 30000;
  next();
});

class Messages {

  constructor() {

    this.model = mongoose.model('messages', modelSchema, 'messages');
  }

  getAllMessages(params, cb) {
    // .... some code
    // .... uses this.model.find()
  };

  insertMessage(params, cb) {
    // .... some code
    let newMessage = new this.model(newObj);
    // uses newMessage.save()
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

This is an example mongoose model I've. The `this.model` seems to cause a lot of memory leak when the model was exported as a singleton like `export default new Messages()`

I further optimized to export just the class like in the main code above and instantiate whenever required. Still looks like it's causing a lot of memory leaks.

Any inputs on what I'm doing here and how should I improve this?

Comment: How are you determining there are memory leaks?

Comment: I could see error logs for out of memory and using `memwatch-next`, generated the heap dump

Comment: your registering messages scheme as model every time your create Messages instance. try outside of class  **var Message = mongoose.model('messages', modelSchema);**  then constructor write   **this.model = Message**

Comment: @vijay The reason why I was doing it in constructor was I wanted the model reference to be cleaned up by GC after I instantiate the class and use it.